# Using c# to set the source of a mediaElement

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to set the source of a media element using c# coding (the video is located in the project's assets folder), my coding is as follow:

```
//Defined as such in my XAML
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"Assets\HarlemCampus.wmv");
mediaElement.Play();
```

...but I am receiving the following error when I click the button to play the video:

[image]

I don't want to preset the source in XAML because I want to dynamically change the media element's source, according to the radiobutton selected by the user at runtime, if there's a way to do this?

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @Clemens I did read the error message. It says there is something wrong with the format of my video location:

Comment: @Clemens The error reads:

Comment: An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: But I tried various alternative formats, without any success

Comment: does it work if you hardcode the whole path?

Comment: @ElenaDBA it works if I specify that path directly in the XAML, but that is not what I need. Maybe there is a way to access a variable defined in my code-behind, within my XAML?

Comment: Try `new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/HarlemCampus.wmv")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a resource file Uri:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/HarlemCampus.wmv");
```